# Bing Maps REST API response does not return any coordinates even response is "OK" and X-MS-BM-WS-INFO is "1"

Tags: rest, dictionary, bing

We have a .NET application that retrieve a geolocation based on unstructured query, e.g., 
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q=Australia%20Homebush%20Bay&key=

In our network the response is "OK" and returned the coordinates in JSON format, but in another network (e.g., customer network), the response is "OK" but the "coordinates" does not return any items, or "0" estimatedTotal.

When we used Fiddler, the X-MS-BM-WS-INFO is "1".

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

This is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701703.aspx under Error Handling. When the X-MS-BM-WS-INFO is "1" this indicates that the request has been rate limited. Rate limiting occurs on trial and basic Bing Maps accounts when the frequency of requests is such that your account will exceed the free usage allowance.